# Requests.Get not working for API call - Yielding 401 Error and "Not Logged In" - Second Call

Tags: python, api

I have successfully connected to the target server using requests.post; however, when I try to make any request.get calls I am receiving the following error:

```
{"message":"Not logged in","code":401}
```

I have confirmed I am logging in successfully, as when I print(response.text) I am showing info from the server. Based on the error message, it appears that I am not persisting the login.

My script:

```
import requests

data = {}
payload = {'j_username': 'my_username', 'j_password': 'my_password'}
response = requests.post('https://sample.com', data=payload)

getBlocks_response = requests.get('https://sample.com/api/v1/resourceBlock')
print(getBlocks_response.text)

getDataDateRange_response = requests.get('https://sample.com/api/v1/factData/getDataDateRange', data=payload)
print(getDataDateRange_response.text)
```

I am expecting an output of data in the form of a JSON, but have only received two errors for both requests.get calls above. I am new to Python as well as API interaction. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I read the documentation regarding Session(). I was able to get my get requests to run successfully by adjusting my script to:

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as session:
data = {}
payload = {'j_username': 'my_username', 'j_password': 'my_password'}
response = session.post('https://sample.com', data=payload)

getBlocks_response = session.get('https://sample.com/api/v1/resourceBlock')
print(getBlocks_response.text)

getDataDateRange_response = session.get('https://sample.com/api/v1/factData/getDataDateRange', data=payload)
print(getDataDateRange_response.text)
```